# Google Maps Static API returns weird image

Tags: google-maps

I have a page that has a static maps URI in the form of http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x240&markers=icon:http://100procentjan.nl/tweakers/punaise.png|shadow:false|52.369010925293,4.8560848236084&sensor=false&zoom=15&center=52.369010925293,4.8560848236084 .

When I visit this page from any browser it shows up just fine, but not when I use it through a Blackberry that is connected through our BES (but same wireless network!). Then this image shows up:

[image: Argh]

Does anyone know what this image means?

Comment: Fails for me too, `403 forbidden`, same graphic. BB personal, no BES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a BB specific issue with Google's static maps API. The API rate limit is normal, but it pops up more often when using BB devices.

They seem to be using an IP pool and rotating those out to devices. This should in theory be a very intermittent issue. If you wait a few days hours, it should go away.

In other words, collectively, your IP has hit the static maps API more than 1000 times in a 24 hours period. This also happens when you hit the API too frequently within a short space of time.

My solution to this was to write a simple PHP script that requested the map image from Google once, saved it as a file and just served it instead of hitting the maps API each time.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$latlng = (isset($_GET['c']))? $_GET['c'] : NULL ;
$zoom   = (isset($_GET['z']))? $_GET['z'] : 9 ;
$file   = "cache/p_$p-z_$zoom.jpg";

if(!file_exists($file))
{
    $parts = array(
        'center'  => $latlng,
        'zoom'    => $zoom,
        'size'    => '320x240',
        'maptype' => 'terrain',
        'sensor'  => 'false',
        'format'  => 'jpeg'
    );      

    file_put_contents(
        $file, file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?".implode('&', $parts))
    );
}

echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: Apparently that's not allowed by google, but hopefully they won't notice :) https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_staticmaps_reuse

Answer (score 5):

You have [exceeded the usage limits](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits) for the specific ip address

"Use of the Google Static Maps API is subject to a query limit of 1000 unique (different) image requests per viewer per day"

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue on various wireless carriers.  I believe it was due to having many users worth of traffic funnel through the same external IP address used by the wireless carrier.  Google sees these all as a single request source.

To fix, make sure you are appending your Google API key to the end of your request for the static map.  Example:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<lat>,<lng>&zoom=17&markers=color:0059A9%7C<lat>,<lng>&size=576x174&sensor=false&key=YOUR_SUPER_LONG_GOOGLE_API_KEY_GOES_HERE`

Answer (score 0):

I get this too, always, on a Blackberry.  Don't think its usage limits, because I just woke up, and my total accesses = 1.  Unless its some shared IP issue related to Blackberry.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has something to do with the way Blackberry handles these requests. Haven't seen this problem on other devices.