# Google static map error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have a problem with static google map with an improper image on my website. Anyone know how this issue occurs? Please see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577807/google-maps-static-api-returns-weird-image/5580475#5580475).You have exceeded the usage limits for the specific ip address.